# QGIS raster calculator returns non-sense low number

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I have a raster with depths (ESRI ASCII DEM format, named "combined_smooth") from "-5" to "6" (positive values are depths, negative land heights).
I want to increase the depth by 2.17 m, and have written the following expression for the raster calculator:

```
("combined_smooth@1" >= 0) * (2.17+"combined_smooth@1")+("combined_smooth@1" < 0)*-5
```

This correctly adds "2.17" to the depths, but also makes the smallest vales in the raster (a height) equal to "-3.40282e+38". Running a second round of the calculator as:

```
("combined_smooth@1"<-5)*-5 + ("combined_smooth@1">=-5)*"combined_smooth@1"
```

yields an identical raster, who's minimal value is still "-3.40282e+38".
I assume this is some sort of NODATA_VALUE, but opening the file in shows NODATA_Value as -9999 and a search in the file find no values like "-3.40282e+38".

Comment: "-3.40282e+38" is negative float-max (minimum representation limit of 4-byte IEEE floating-point value)

Comment: Yes I figured as much, but still strange that the expression: "aRaster<-5" does not pick that up, surely "-3.40282e+38" is smaller than "-5". So QGIS must give this number a separate attribute such as "low(float)" or something similar... Grrrr....

Answer (score 1):

Using the method provided here to find and change all values to a chosen value, makes the above expression work.

TLDR:

1. Turn off tick in layer properties/No data value
2. use Processing/GRASS/r.null to replace "-3.40282e+38" with other value
3. Use raster calculator succesfully

Solution to eliminate "-3.40282e+38" from raster:
[Changing nodata pixels of -3.40282347e+38 to a different number in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340893/changing-nodata-pixels-of-3-40282347e38-to-a-different-number-in-qgis)